# React rerenders even if nothing changed in context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have this code taken out from my app could someone take a look at it please, its simplified, but similar to actual implementation where notifications are shared between multiple components
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bouman-v74rb

**My Question is : Why does toggling box in `Header` cause `Notifications` to re-render?**
In mobile toggling that box is very very slow, which im guessing is cuz of whole app re-rendering. But **why is local state of Header causing other component to re-render as well?**

Any resource on learning more about the topic would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Please publish relevant code in your question in addition to your codesandbox.

Comment: Looks like you're using a shared context for both components. When the context changes in one component, the other component that uses the shared context gets re-rendered, too.

Comment: @jmargolisvt codesandbox does have relevant code for my question.

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali but in Navigation im only toggling local state, it should change anything in context 